# Weird behaviour in assembler code of C

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

Let me put the situation clearly, i was learning about c data types with gdb.

```
int main(){
int integer = 2;
return 0;
}
```

- First i introduced a `int` in my program which is 4 bytes `x86` which
  generated an acceptable assembler code as follows.

  > ```
  > 0x00000000004004ad <+1>:  mov    %rsp,%rbp   
  > 0x00000000004004b0 <+4>:  movl   $0x2,-0x4(%rbp)
  > ```

Then i believe something went wrong here i decided to experiment with a `char null_byte = '\0'`

```
int main(){
char nul_byte = '\0';
int integer = 2;
return 0;
}
```

- Now i am new to c and according to what i have learned char uses 1 byte, so i initialized the `char null_byte = '\0'` in my program and the resulting assembler code was weired , below.

> ```
>      0x00000000004004ad <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
>      0x00000000004004b0 <+4>: movb   $0x0,-0x1(%rbp)
>      0x00000000004004b4 <+8>: movl   $0x2,-0x8(%rbp)
> ```

now help me with something why is base pointer displacing 8 bytes to low rather than 4 after introducing `null_byte char`?

Comment: Search for and read about *alignment*.

Comment: That's due to stack pointer alignment which should be multiple of 8 . Also, the compiler is free to use whatever memory layout it wishes, and it decided to pack the char and the int into the same qword.

Comment: srry guys i am kind of new to c. So a qword thats intresting does this happen with 2 ints also?

Comment: and the 3 remaining bytes of the char are wasted or used by int>?

Comment: Use *@* along with the username to ping / notify other users. Example @Jester pinged Jester. More information about this [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). Google _padding_ / _alignment_ to know the answer to your question.

Comment: The 3 remaining bytes are wasted in this scenario, yes. If you have 2 ints, the compiler will probably pack them into the same qword (which is 8 bytes) so no space will be wasted.

Comment: thanks @Jester, i am reading data alignment now.